# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier in Hibernate @OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a bidirectional @OneToMany / @ManyToOne relationship in the below entities:

```
@Entity
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {

    // other columns including ID
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long itemId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "packageId")
    private Package package;        
}

@Entity
public class Package {

    // other columns including ID
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="package", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(0);
}
```

Suppose initially there's a package without items and to add items to that package, when I try to get a package by its Id `packageRepository.findOne(packageId)` (Spring Data JPA code), I get the below error at that line.

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.generateEntityKey(AbstractSessionImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:707)
```

I think the Hibernate tries a left outer join and finds that itemId (Id for `Item` entity) is null. I do need to have the EAGER fetch there. What's the workaround for this issue? How do I retrieve a package when there are no items?

Comment: Could you post the ID fields in the classes?

Comment: My guess is that either your mapping of ID is wrong, or that you have a null ID in the database. To know what the SQL query is, enable SQL logging and see by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet Added Id fields. There are no items in the table while retrieving the package. So left outer join of package to item (from the SQL logging) results in null `itemId`.

Comment: You could also check if your database table is set to generate the primary key values i.e. "Auto increment" on you id field in DB.

Comment: @Jayasagar Yes, that works as expected, not a problem.

Comment: Show us the real code, because the bug is in the real code, and not in the fake code you're showing us. The class Item doesn't compile, because package is a reserved Java keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **@NotFound** annotation:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="package", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(0);
```

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html

This may not be the best cure to your problem. Hibernate docs describe the use of @NotFound as:

> When Hibernate cannot resolve the association because the expected
>   associated element is not in database (wrong id on the association
>   column), an exception is raised. This might be inconvenient for legacy
>   and badly maintained schemas. You can ask Hibernate to ignore such
>   elements instead of raising an exception using the @NotFound
>   annotation.

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried this yet. But I don't get - `for legacy and badly maintained schemas`. I thought my use-case was very common. Having a one-to-many relationship with initial package having no items. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I think your case is quite common and can't tell exactly why it fails. I just began to think: could it be that once the items are LEFT JOINed in the query, hibernate tries to load the associated package (but why?), which clearly has null identifier and that is actually the thing that fails?

Comment: In the LEFT JOIN of package to item, `itemId` comes out as Null because there are no items associated with that package. But not sure how get around that.

Comment: Finding the root cause and fix it will be the best solution  not the alternative suggested in this answer by @heikkim

Comment: @Jayasagar That's true. It would be nice if Stack Overflow had this "suggest solution" -kind of thing in addition to hard answers and short comments.

Comment: There's something wrong in your code or mappings. Can you post any code relating to loading/creating entities?